# SQL - Display a row twice while ordering the "duplicate repush" by date created

Tags: php, mysql, union-all

I have a table ("comments") full of comments, the date they were created, and, if they were pushed to the front via a PHP button, the date of that also (otherwise the date will be '0000-00-00'). What I'd like is the table to be displayed as normal, but to have the comments that were "repushed" to be pushed to a place within the table with an `ORDER BY` of date created ("created").

Here's an example of what I'd like to achieve, which involes pushing an old comment (ID: 4) to the top (NOTE: there are no duplicates ID's in the table, only the query result will duplicate repushed records as shown here):

```
id | comment | created             | repushed
---+---------+---------------------+-------------------
4  | hello   | 2015-05-11 06:11:12 | 2015-11-22 11:17:01
23 | recent  | 2015-05-22 12:18:23 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
22 | recent  | 2015-05-22 11:15:43 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
21 | recent  | 2015-05-22 10:23:10 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
4  | hello   | 2015-05-11 06:11:12 | 2015-11-22 11:17:01
```

So I'm trying to use `UNION` to combine all comments with repushed comments (so all repushed comments will *appear* duplicated once queried), but then I want to treat the duplicated repushed comments as if they were created at the time they were repushed, so I would need to swap the "created" and "repushed" column values of duplicates to get this effect, and then order by "created".

```
SELECT *
FROM comments
WHERE repushed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
UNION ALL                         
SELECT *
FROM comments
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Of course this doesn't work as intended since I don't know how to swap the two column values around.

Comment: Could you add your expected result?

Comment: Hi. The table I've shown here is my expected/intended result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with what you already have try this:

```
SELECT id,comment,repushed as created,repushed 
FROM comments   
WHERE repushed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' group by id
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM comments group by id ORDER BY created DESC
```

This will rename the column repushed to created

Comment: shouldn't it be ordering only on the 2nd union select?

Comment: I got: Database query failed: Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: try my edit (removed the order by to within the brackets)

Comment: Still the same error. I'm not really following the use of SELECT * FROM (<whole query>), could you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: previously it was to order by created over all data, after @Justin comment I removed that ordering, so it's not needed anymore.

Comment: Gotcha. Now it's saying: Database query failed: Column 'created' in order clause is ambiguous. How do I reference to a singular 'created' column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95883/discussion-between-davejal-and-justin).